# Split polygon using offset distance method in ArcGIS using VB.NET/C#

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcobjects

I am developing the extension on ArcMap for custom mapping solution.I have the requirement for splitting the polygon on ArcMap using VB.NET or C#. The algorithm is something like below-

Given as line on the polygon, the split operation should cut the polygon using offset line and area technique. I have prepared image below which may illustrate the scenario.
[image]

Does anyone has clue or snippet which does the same?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your code so far look like?

Comment: I solved this using  IConstructLine.ConstructExtended() method